# Cutter console does not show printf result

Tags: reverse-engineering, reversing, radare2

0

I'm using last version (2.0.5) of Cutter. I am not able to find a way to display std in/out in Cutter Console. In the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WI2Jw.jpg) I cleared the console before starting debugging and you can see it after the call to the printf. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks, L.

I tried both 2.0.4 and 2.0.3 without any benefit. Actually I realized it is a buffering problem, indeed continuing debugging the output comes out after the return. Yet the problem comes when you have to provide an input. Let's consider the simple crackme in [image: picture] debugging gets stucked on the "fgets" call waiting for an input...but I have no way to provide an input. I tried both "Input to the debugger" and "razin console" both of them results with the input being sent to Razin (see console) and the program still blocked.
Any suggestion?

Comment: It's a regression from 2.0.4, you can use that version it will work.

Comment: No, I tried both 2.0.4 and 2.0.3 this didn't solve the problem. I edited the question with additional info. Thanks.

Comment: Well, on my machine running ubuntu 20.04 and using their 2.0.4 release from github, it indeed works whereas 2.0.5 did not.

Comment: I updated ubuntu to the Focal release, nevertheless I got the same kind of issue.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm the same issue with 2.0.5.
Setting the english language seems to temporarily solve the problem with input. Output messages still appears after the return tough.

Comment: Please delete this answer and like question and/or follow question if you need answer in it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That's a good tip, I switched to English and the issue with the input was solved...still there is a problem of buffering for output. Thanks.